# Interface orientation not changing automatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am not able to change the interface orientation in my universal app. It has a navigation controller. I have added a view controller to the navigation controller and added the navigation controller's view to the window. If I remove the navigation controller and add the view controller's view to the window as a subview, then it recognizes the orientation, but if I add the navigation controller's view, the interface orientation is not changing. Please help me with some reference. The following is my code.
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
     {

```
 if ([self.view isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
     UIViewController *rootController = [((UINavigationController*)self.view).viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        return [rootController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
    }
return YES;

}
```

Comment: Please help us help you by including relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to override the `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` method. By default, a UIViewController only returns yes for portrait mode.

Comment: Thanks. So u mean should I override this method for UINavigationController.Can I get any reference for that?